# Can Applications developed using Windows 8.1 SDK be targetted for Windows 10 platform?

Tags: visual-studio, winapi

I have a C++ project written using Visual Studio 2017. In the project `'Properties'` , Under `General` section i have `Target Platform` and `Windows SDK Version`.

When i change the `'Windows SDK version'` to `8.1`, then i observe that the `Target Platform` stays set to `'Windows 10'` and i have no option of editing that as well. I was thinking that Windows 8.1 SDK can only be used to develop applications for Windows 8. Isn't that right?

Hence shouldn't the `Target Platform` property be automatically changed to `'Windows 8'` when i changed `'Windows SDK version'` to `8.1`? I can't even edit the `Target Platform` property which stays greyed out to `Windows 10`.

Is it possible that i can use Windows SDK 8.1 and still develop programs for `Windows 10`?

Comment: @llnspectable - the ones with the question marks. But i think this one is valid as well ---> Is it possible that i can use Windows SDK 8.1 and still develop programs for Windows 10?

Comment: possible, in what problem? of course you will be use only definitions available for win8.1

Comment: What do you mean @RbMm. It's a generic question. My intention is to know that why the target platform value is set to 'Windows 10' only? And why is that uneditable? What if I want to use windows 8.1 SDK for Windows 8 or any earlier version? The hardcoded and uneditable value for target platform is confusing me. Why is that so? Does it mean that using vs2017 , the target platform will only be Windows 10? What does it imply?

Comment: really all this - is only indirect way for select path for sdk/wdk header/lib files which you will be use in compilation/build process. nothing more. this is absolute unrelated to version of windows where your code will be (can be) run. you can use win10 sdk and build app which will be run even on xp (if you will be use only xp api set). and you can use say win7 sdk and build app which will be ok run on win10 and more new windows.

Comment: @RbMm - yes I understand this. My question is why is the value hardcoded to windows 10 for target platform? As per common logic targetPlatform means the platform which is targeted.

Comment: this already question for setting, installation and interface of concrete visual-studio

Comment: @J.Snow `Is it possible that i can use Windows SDK 8.1 and still develop programs for Windows 10?` Yes, of course. Do you think an app you build against the Win10 SDK today will suddenly stop working if MS releases Win11 tomorrow?

Comment: @dxiv 6 - yes that part is clear but my question on hardcoding of targetPlatform to Windows10 still remains open.

Comment: @J.Snow `Target Platform` in VS 2017 is just an informational field which auto-updates based on the selected Platform. It is set to `Windows 10` for x86/x64/ARM, but for example it is blank for Itanium. It used to be labeled just `Windows` in VS 2015, and I believe it was changed to `Windows 10` only to drive the point that MS considers all other/older Windows versions to be obsolete.

Comment: @J.Snow That doesn't hardcod to Windows 10 for your project. Which version do you want to target depending on which Windows SDK do you choose. You can change it via Windows SDK version in project properties or use Macros for Conditional Declarations of [Windows hearders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/WinProg/using-the-windows-headers). Refer to "[How to: Use the Windows 10 SDK in a Windows Desktop application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/how-to-use-the-windows-10-sdk-in-a-windows-desktop-application?view=vs-2017)".